# How can I use the Numba with boolean in coffea framework?

Tags: numba, awkward-array

```
@numba.njit
def make_vid_plot(Photon):
       
hoe_arr=[]
sieie_arr=[]
Isochg_arr = []



for eventIdx,pho in enumerate(Photon):
    for phoIdx,_ in enumerate(pho):
        vid = Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].vidNestedWPBitmap
        vid_cuts1 = PhotonVID(vid,1)
        vid_cuts2 = PhotonVID(vid,2)
        vid_cuts3 = PhotonVID(vid,3)

        if (vid_cuts2 & 0b1110111 == 0b1110111): # without sieie
            
            print(Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].isScEtaEE) # isEcEtaEE is boolean 
            hoe_arr.append(Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].hoe)
            sieie_arr.append(Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].sieie)
            Isochg_arr.append(Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].pfRelIso03_chg)
    
return hoe_arr,sieie_arr,Isochg_arr
```

Error message  ##############################

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at resolving type of attribute "isScEtaEE" of "$112binary_subscr.7".
module 'numba' has no attribute 'bool'
During: typing of get attribute at  (19)
Enable logging at debug level for details.
File "", line 19:
def make_vid_plot(Photon):

print(Photon[eventIdx][phoIdx].isScEtaEE) # isEcEtaEE is boolean
^

###########################

I'm using numba with Coffea but, Numba with boolean seems now working.
How to solve this error?

numba version: 0.51.2

Thank you

Comment: There's not enough information in the part of the error message that has been displayed, but it might be a bug in Awkward Array if `numba.bool` was supposed to be `numba.types.boolean` in https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/blob/7fc6d26a14484e684540ce847e8c412385a382f9/src/awkward/_connect/_numba/layout.py#L565

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this was a bug in Awkward Array that was fixed in [PR #776](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/pull/776), which will probably be merged into the `main` branch by the time you read this.

I recognize that it can be difficult to distinguish user errors from internal bugs from the error messages—the general rule in Awkward Array is that `RuntimeError` is an internal bug, `ValueError` is a user error—but any error when Numba is trying to determine a type is presented as `TypeError`, regardless of what it is. (In this case, it was an `AttributeError`! It was trying to access `numba.bool` when the correct spelling is `numba.boolean`.)

However, if you think that something might be a bug, it would be easier if you report it as a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/issues). It is also helpful to print out the whole error message, like this:

```
E           numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
E           No implementation of function Function(<built-in function getitem>) found for signature:
E            
E            >>> getitem(ak.ArrayView(ak.VirtualArrayType({"class":"ListOffsetArray64","offsets":"i64","content":{"class":"RecordArray","contents":{"x":{"class":"NumpyArray","inner_shape":[],"itemsize":1,"format":"?","primitive":"bool","has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}, none, {}), None, ()), Literal[int](2))
E            
E           There are 28 candidate implementations:
E             - Of which 26 did not match due to:
E             Overload of function 'getitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
E               With argument(s): '(ak.ArrayView(ak.VirtualArrayType({"class":"ListOffsetArray64","offsets":"i64","content":{"class":"RecordArray","contents":{"x":{"class":"NumpyArray","inner_shape":[],"itemsize":1,"format":"?","primitive":"bool","has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}, none, {}), None, ()), int64)':
E              No match.
E             - Of which 2 did not match due to:
E             Overload in function 'type_getitem.generic': File: ../../../../irishep/awkward-1.0/awkward/_connect/_numba/arrayview.py: Line 575.
E               With argument(s): '(ak.ArrayView(ak.VirtualArrayType({"class":"ListOffsetArray64","offsets":"i64","content":{"class":"RecordArray","contents":{"x":{"class":"NumpyArray","inner_shape":[],"itemsize":1,"format":"?","primitive":"bool","has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null},"has_identities":false,"parameters":{},"form_key":null}, none, {}), None, ()), int64)':
E              Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
E                AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'bool'
E             raised from /home/jpivarski/irishep/awkward-1.0/awkward/_connect/_numba/layout.py:565
E           
E           During: typing of intrinsic-call at /home/jpivarski/irishep/awkward-1.0/tests/test_0776-numba-booleans-in-array.py (16)
E           During: typing of static-get-item at /home/jpivarski/irishep/awkward-1.0/tests/test_0776-numba-booleans-in-array.py (16)
E           
E           File "tests/test_0776-numba-booleans-in-array.py", line 16:
E               def f1(array):
E                   return array[2][0].x
E                   ^

../../miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:357: TypingError
```

The part of the error message that you quoted, luckily enough, included the part "`module 'numba' has no attribute 'bool'`", which gave me a place to start. But it was crucial to understanding this bug that `Photon` is a virtual array—the offending `numba.bool` happens in virtual array-handling. (Coffea NanoEvents are virtual—they read data from ROOT files on demand, even inside a Numba JIT-compiled function.) The full error message includes the fact that this array has `VirtualArrayType`.

The *best* bug reports include some data to reproduce the issue (i.e. how did you get the `Photon` object?), but the [GitHub Issue template](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug+%28unverified%29&template=bug-report.md&title=) prompts you for this.

Thanks for reporting this, though! Any report helps!